# sign_blob usage

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to [sign](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/functions.html) some blob and send back the signature to the user.
How can the user verify the signature? It would be good to have an
example of how to obtain the public certificate and process the signature.

Comment: Have you looked at the [get_public_certificates](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/functions.html) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but I still found it difficult to find an example of how to do this! So I'm posting my solution in case someone else is looking into how to verify a signature from `sign_blog`. Its funny that google's python page ends with

> Here is an example showing how to sign a blob and validate its signature:

without any examples.

After searching around I found one example on [this page](https://swarming.googlecode.com/git-history/a97a584ba8c589979f57c3bd36424aca4004fd2d/appengine/components/components/auth/signature.py). This is how the author of that code does the signing:

```python
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

def sign_blob(blob):
    """Signs a blob using current service's private key.

    Uses GAE app_identity.sign_blob function. It has a limit of 8KB on a size of
    a blob, so |blob| is hashed first (with sha512). So final signature is
    RSA+SHA256(sha512(blob)).

    Returns:
      Tuple (name of a key used, signature).
    """
    # app_identity.sign_blob is producing RSA+SHA256 signature. Sadly, it isn't
    # documented anywhere. But it should be relatively stable since this API is
    # used by OAuth2 libraries (and so changing signature method may break a lot
    # of stuff).
    return app_identity.sign_blob(hashlib.sha512(blob).digest())
```

The same author goes on to use `pycrypto` for the verification. The function is called `check_signature`,  near the bottom of the page. It works just fine, but `pycrypto` doesn't look like it is actively updated.

An implementation I came up with uses `cryptography` which has active development. Check it out:

```python
import base64

from google.appengine.api import app_identity

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature

def verify_signature(key_name, signature, data):

    # Decode the signature
    try:
        signature = base64.b64decode(signature)
    except TypeError:
        return False

    # Get the list of certificates app engine has been using
    certs = app_identity.get_public_certificates()

    # Match the key with a certificate
    x509_cert_pem = None
    for cert in certs:
        if cert.key_name == key_name:
            x509_cert_pem = cert.x509_certificate_pem
            break

    # Check that a certifcate matched
    if not x509_cert_pem:
        return False

    # Create x509 cert object
    x509_cert = load_pem_x509_certificate(x509_cert_pem, backend=default_backend())

    # Extract the public key
    public_key = x509_cert.public_key()

    # Prep the verifier
    verifier = public_key.verifier(
        signature,
        padding.PKCS1v15(),
        hashes.SHA256()
    )
    verifier.update(data)

    # No return value documented. Raises an error on mismatch
    # https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/interfaces/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.AsymmetricVerificationContext.verify # noqa
    try:
        result = verifier.verify()
    except InvalidSignature:
        return False

    return (result is None)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/overview.html#Asserting_Identity_to_Other_Systems), using `get_public_certificates` you can get the certificates to validate signature.

[Public certificates](http://code.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity.py&q=sign_blob%20package%3ahttp://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=117) are plain Python object, with a `key_name` and `x509_certificate_pem` properties.

`sign_blob` [returns](http://code.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity.py&q=sign_blob%20package%3ahttp://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=184) the `key_name` that was used to sign the blob and the `signature` in a tuple.

Then you should be able to verify the signature with the x509 certificate using any crypto library.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out the `get_public_certificates` method. My question was more from the point of view of the receiver of the signature and how they can process the signature. I guess this means that I must also send the public certificate along with signature.